# Field Integrity Exception: Unknown when updating a price in sandbox

Tags: sandbox, opportunity-lineitem, quotelineitem, pricebookentry

In sandbox, I am trying to update a price for a product in the standard price book through the UI. When I change the List Price and click save, I get the following error. These are referencing opportunitylineitem records.

> field integrity exception: unknown
> (00k0H00000kxUx4|1|1||10000||1,00k0H00000lIWrD|1|1||25000||1,00k0H00000lJo5q|1|1||22892||1,00k0H00000ldtxn|1|1||20000||1,00k0H00000mHXub|1|1||51500||1,)

This seems to only happen in sandbox.
I had read that `Use Standard Price` can cause an issue so I tried to uncheck the `Use Standard Price` from other Price Book Entries, but I'm still getting a similar error:

> field integrity exception: unknown with opportunitylineitem records
> listed also

Any ideas?

Comment: This may mean that a feature that is required isn't enabled or something similar.

Comment: Can you raise case with salesforce support to fix the issue.

Comment: Looks related to the scenario mentioned in https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000315525&type=1 . Salesforce support can run scrutiny to fix the issue.

Comment: I have submitted a ticket. I will let you know what happens.